# In machine learning, what are things you can do to limit the number of required training samples?

Tags: machine-learning

In many applications, creating a large training dataset can be very costly, if not outright impossible. So what steps can one take to limit the size that is needed for good accuracy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there is a branch of machine learning specifically dedicated to solve this problem (labeling datasets is costly) : [semi-supervised learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-supervised_learning)

Honestly, from my experience, the computation is quite horrendously long and the results pale in comparison with fully labeled datasets... But better train on a large unlabeled dataset rather than with nothing!

---

Edit : Well, I first understood the question as "Labeling a dataset is expensive" rather than "The size of the dataset will be small no matter what"

Well, among other things, I would :

- Tune my parameters with the [leave one out cross validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29#Common_types_of_cross-validation). The most computationnaly expensive, but the best one.
- Choose algorithms that have a rather quick convergence. (You need a comparison table, which I do not have right now)
- Need very good generalization properties. Linear combinations of weak classifiers are quite good in this case. kNN (k nearest neighbours) are extremely bad.
- Bias the "generalization" parameter. Most algorithm consist in a compromise between generalization (regularity) and quality (is the training set well classified by the classifier?). If your dataset is small, you should bias the algorithm toward generalization (after tuning the parameters with cross validation)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was thinking about the problem more in terms of designing the learning method and model to cope with the small dataset size, but your answer sheds some interesting light on the question.

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad. I've edited my post, but as I can't talk from experience (never had this problem before), I gave some hints, but I can't guarantee them!